# Secondary pseudo-random unique key for records using Ruby on Rails and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, uniqueidentifier

I want to add a secondary generated key for my tables in a Ruby on Rails application that currently uses a PostgreSQL database. If possible I'd like to be database agnostic. The goal is to use this keys on URLs so external users can't guess the size of the database or the amount of records of each type I have.

I know about UUIDs but they are long and an overkill. Also, this field should be indexed and I understand that random data in an index is problematic.

If there's no clean solution, I'll just make a little formula to apply to the id and make sure I check for collisions and avoid them; but I'm sure I'm not the first one to have this problem.

Comment: Random data in an index isn't a problem. Random data in a *clustered* index might be a problem, though.

Comment: With respect to UUIDs, are you rejecting them because 16 bytes is too long? If so, how many bytes is just long enough?

Comment: Catcall: probably 6 bytes is enough, I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking of doing this:

```
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n * 3).gsub(/[A-Z\-_]/, "")[0..n]
```

where n is a safe base starting number... I'd say, 5 or 6. I filter out some characters I don't want in the id. When there's a database collision, I run it again but I increment n, so if a table suddenly gets a crazy amount of records, it shouldn't take that many tries to find an available one.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar to this in the past, I used SHA hashes that where made from a string from the id and created_at, or anything you please that will make it an unique string, and do a hexdigest.

something like, code not tested

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( self.id.to_s + self.created_at.to_s )
```

Even if you manage to create the record at the same time, the id should give you a unique string.
It wont guarantee complete uniqueness, since it is a hash, but the chances are slim, and you could run a check to make sure if there are any duplicates, or set the database as so if possible.

hope this helps.

Comment: My only problem with that is that it's too long for my taste.